# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject and multi org connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, multi-org

We would like to capture preference modifications from the cloud page and set them near real time  in salesforce custom preference object.

As the function UpdateSingleSalesforceObject do not have any place to mention org id etc., would it be fair to expect that it will update object from the connected salesforce org to that particular BU?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have multi-org enabled, you can only connect one BU to one SF org, so this function run on a CloudPage in a particular BU will update data in the connected SF org.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!